# Naming SwipeJS objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, swipe

How can I name a Swipe (from [swipeJS](https://github.com/thebird/Swipe)) object when a create one?

```
window.mySwipe = new Swipe(document.getElementById("#someId"), {
            speed: 1400,
            auto: 400,

        })
```

Comment: What do you mean "name"?

Comment: given a name to the Swipe object like when you name a var..as I see in this case looks like it's not possible

Comment: ...the "name" is `mySwipe`. What am I missing?

Comment: mySwipe looks like an atribute of window to me

Comment: `window.mySwipe` is the same as a global `var mySwipe`. Just change `mySwipe` to whatever you want.